# Add keyboard support to website dropdown navigation

Tags: jquery, html, css

I know Suckerfish does this very well, but I don't like the javascript in Suckerfish and figured there must be an easier way to do this using jQuery. I've done up the following page:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
      "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <title>Test nav page</title>
    <style type="text/css">

        html {margin:0;padding:0;text-align:center;font-size:62.5%}
        body {margin:0 auto;padding:0;width:600px;text-align:left;}

        ul#nav {display:inline-block;width:260px;border:0;float:right;list-style:none;position:relative;}
            ul#nav li {display:inline-block;float:left;width:130px;font-family:arial;color:#444;font-size:1.2em;font-weight:bold;text-align:center;position:relative;}
            ul#nav li.t1, ul#nav li.t1 ul li a {background-color:#aad;}
            ul#nav li.t2, ul#nav li.t2 ul li a {background-color:#daa;}
                ul#nav li ul {position:absolute;left:-9999px;display:block;width:130px}
                    ul#nav li:hover ul,ul#nav li.hover ul, ul#nav li:focus ul {left:-40px;}

                ul#nav li a {display:block;width:120px;padding:7px 5px;}
                    ul#nav li ul li a {border-top:solid 1px #ddd;font-size:0.9em;padding:7px 0;width:130px;display:inline-block}


    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul id="nav">
            <li class="t1"><a href="#top1" tabindex="1">Top one</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#first" tabindex="2">First</a></li>
                <li><a href="#second" tabindex="3">Second</a></li>
            </ul></li>
            <li class="t2"><a href="#top2" tabindex="4">Top two</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#third" tabindex="5">Third</a></li>
                <li><a href="#fourth" tabindex="6">Fourth</a></li>
            </ul></li>
        </ul>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" >
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('ul#nav li').hover(
                function(){
                    $(this).toggleClass('hover');
                });
// Updated with the following jQuery Function...
            $('ul#nav li a').focus(
            function(){
                $(this).parent().addClass('hover');
        });
// Just need a way of closing the dropdown when the key focus moves out of the li, not the anchor...
        });
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

And it all works great EXCEPT that it's inaccessible with the keyboard. Can anyone point out what I'm missing!? It's just baffling me, been at it for the past 2 hours and getting nowhere fast.

Cheers,

T

**Update:** I'm really close! I've added another jQuery function which applies the "hover" class to the parent LI if the focus is on the anchor tag. I've added it in the code above. This will allow me to tab onto the link and shows the dropdown links, but once I tab past that (I've also updated the tabindex) they won't disappear.

T

Comment: By the way, the jQuery library is 1.4.4. Not that I think that makes much difference, but just fyi. Also I kept all the script and styling inline so that it makes it easier for you to see what my plan was. Cheers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following

```
        <script type="text/javascript" >
    $(function(){
      //for ie6
      $('#nav li').hover(function(){ $(this).addClass('hover') }, function(){$(this).removeClass('hover')});

      $('#nav a').focus(function(){
        $(this).parents('li').addClass('hover');
      });

      $('#nav a').blur(function(){
        $(this).parents('li').removeClass('hover');
      });
    })
    </script>
```

NOTE: I changed the toggleClass because I don't trust it. I think you should specify what you want to happen with the class otherwise you risk getting stuck in a state that you didn't expect.

Comment: YOU SIR! Are a gentleman and a scholar. That works perfectly now. I agree, I'm not generally a fan of toggleClass, I used it here for suncinct code. My thoughts were that the IE6 hover function wasn't as important as the one for the keyboard switching which was my primary concern. You've made this Jedi a very happy camper!!!